# Replace an occurrence in several files with sed

Tags: sed

I have more than 30 files where I have to replace the occurrence

`msgstr ""` preceded by `msgid "(aged %s)`

by the contents of

`msgstr "..."` belonging to the first occurrence of `msgid "(aged %s)`

All the files are located in directory `resources/`:

```
resources
   lang-fr
       file.po
   lang-ge
       file.po
   lang-it
       file.po
```

If this could help there are only 3 occurrences of `msgid "(aged %s)` per file.

File: `file.po`

```
...
...
msgid "(aged %s)
msgstr "good translation %s"
...
...
msgid "(aged %s)
msgstr ""
...
....
msgid "(aged %s)
msgstr ""
....
....
```

Expected result:

File: `file.po`

```
....
...
msgid "(aged %s)
msgstr "good translation %s"
...
...
msgid "(aged %s)
msgstr "good translation %s"
...
....
msgid "(aged %s)
msgstr "good translation %s"
....
....
```

I've spent a few hours trying with sed, but I'm stuck.

Comment: I doubt you can do this only with `sed` (at least not easily) but you can do it with `awk` or `perl`. I think you will probably get more positive responses if you show your best attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: Use `msgmerge --update` and you'll  have to insert new translation manually anyway. Wait, you have _multiple_ same `msgid` in your translation files? What for? Just remove the redundant ones.

Comment: To KamilCuk. No I want to pass from a msgid --> msgctx,msgid (MALE/FEMALE) context. Once the transformation is done, I want to remove the first msgid entry (without the context) This is just to no lose the translation

Comment: Agree with above, please show (what you think is) your best attempt to solve the problem, Then we can help you improve your skills. (Also agree this is probably better solved with `awk`, but let's see what you have, before we decide). Good show including sample input and required output! Good luck.

Comment: Sorry as highlighted I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

With a shell variable, and two instances of `sed`:

```
r="$(sed -n '/^msgid "(aged %s)$/{n;s/^[^"]*"//p;q}' file.po)"
sed '/^msgid "(aged %s)$/{n;s/\(^msgstr "\)"$/\1'"$r"'/}' file.po
```

After the first run of `sed`, the variable `$r` will contain *`good translation %s"`*.  The next `sed` pass looks for `""` and substitutes it with `$r`.

It could also be done uglier without the variable:

```
sed '/^msgid "(aged %s)$/{n;s/\(^msgstr "\)"$/\1'"$(sed -n '/^msgid "(aged %s)$/{n;s/^[^"]*"//p;q}' file.po)"'/}' file.po
```

---

See also *Baeldung*'s useful survey [Using sed to Replace a Multi-Line String](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/sed-replace-multi-line-string).

Answer (score 0):

For now I have only following script which do not what expected

```
#!/bin/bash
find resources/lang -name '*.po' -exec sed '/^msgid "(aged %s)$/!b
n;/^msgstr "/!b
x;/^$/x;h' {} \;
```

For now unfortunately Input = Output

```
#: app/Age.php:183
#, php-format
msgid "(aged %s)"
msgstr "objective"


#. I18N: The age of an individual at a given date for a Male individual
#: app/Age.php:184
#, php-format
msgctxt "MALE"
msgid "(aged %s)"
msgstr ""


#. I18N: The age of an individual at a given date for a Female individual
#: app/Age.php:188
#, php-format
msgctxt "FEMALE"
msgid "(aged %s)"
msgstr ""
```

Comment: Let it be I will do it with PHP. You can close the topic. I guess that sed was a potential solution , however it might not be the case